# Does it make sense to Order by a column not included in Result Set?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I found myself in a position to migrate below query from MySQL to SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    ass.audio_id,
    SUM(au.audiolength) AS AudioFileLength
FROM    Table1 ass,
        Table2 au
WHERE au.audioid = ass.audio_id
AND ass.auserid = '001'
AND ass.delflag = 0
AND au.delflag = 0
AND tflag = 0
AND ass.serverflag = 1
ORDER BY ass.statflag DESC, ass.serverflag DESC
```

Query works well in MySQL. But in SQL Server, there are two issues:

- I need to GROUP BY `audio_id` >> understood
- SQL Server would not allow me to ORDER BY `statflag` & `serverflag`
  for obvious reason they are not included in `GROUP BY` nor they are
  in AGGREGATE function.

**Questions:**

- In MySQL query as above, Does it make sense to order by a column not included in result set? Would it be **safe migration** if I ignore `ORDER BY` while migrating to SQL Server?
- What is the smartest work-around for above MySQL query into SQL
  Server?

Comment: Sorting by serverflag is irrelevant since it is always going to be 1 per your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version that will work in both databases:

```
SELECT ass.audio_id, SUM(au.audiolength) AS AudioFileLength
FROM cur_assigntable ass JOIN
     cur_audiofile_master au
     ON au.audioid = ass.audio_id
WHERE ass.auserid = '141' AND
      ass.delflag = 0 AND
      au.delflag = 0 AND
      tflag = 0 AND
      ass.serverflag = 1
GROUP BY ass.audio_id
ORDER BY MIN(ass.statflag) DESC, MIN(ass.serverflag) DESC;
```

This fixes the `join` syntax to use explicit joins (always the preferred way to join tables).  It adds the `group by`.  The original query in MySQL would have returned only one row.  It changes the `order by` to use aggregation functions.

There are situations where you want to order by a column not in the result set.  I don't know how the results are being used, so it is hard to say.  Normally, I would include such columns in the `select`.

Comment: Thanks, `original query in MySQL would have returned only one row` -- thats an eye opener, So I do not need an `order by` clause, do I?

Comment: *"Normally, I would include such columns in the select."* Normally, I would too. Sooner or later--usually sooner--somebody will complain that the order is wrong. Having such columns in the `select` clause makes it easy to see the problem. And you don't have to display *every* column or expression that's in the `select` clause.

Comment: @Abhijeet . . . Presumably, the intention is to get one row per `audio_id`.  If not, remove the `audio_id` from the `select`, the `group by` clause, and the `order by` clause.